# Kdenlive Codec Error when Trying to Render MP4

Tags: windows, codec, rendering, kdenlive

Please correct me If I am posting this in the wrong place :)

So, I recently installed Kdenlive on my Windows 10 PC (I would install it on my linux, but this PC is faster). I make my video, then when I go to render it, the MP4 has a big red 'X' next to it. When I click on it it says:

```
Unsupported Video Codec: libx264
```

I can't install the package because i'm on a Windows PC. Soo.... What do I do now?

It's a pain to export in WebM or MPEG

Here's a screen shot:

[KdenLive Codec Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlxZ7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how it even got like this. I restarted Kdenlive and then tried to render it. It didn't show the RED 'X'. I think that it didn't recognize the codec's were actually installed in the first place. Now I can sucessfully export MP4's :)

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem. Did you change anything before rebooting?

Comment: Actually, (I forgot to include this) the MP4 did export, BUT the video returned blank... I just ended up using WebM, then I used handbrake to convert it to MP4.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to download FFMPEG version 3.4.1 here: https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/shared/ffmpeg-3.4.1-win64-shared.zip. You can find out more about this solution here: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=265&t=142695&sid=e668ff6e65fabe825b071278e4baf4f8&start=15 (see DrQuantumos, ARPcPro, and jfahy's replies).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.